# Select form in PHP sending bytes into serial

Tags: php, serial-port, arduino

I need some help with my php site. I would like to use simple select form (size 1) for temperature and after I select it, I would like to auto send it into serial port. At the moment I've got simple script where I can select one option (on or off) to light single diode on my Arduino, scripts looks like:

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {

    require("php_serial.class.php");

        $serial = new phpSerial();
        $serial->deviceSet("COM3");
        $serial->confBaudRate(9600);
        $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
        $serial->deviceOpen();

if ($_GET['action'] == "on") {

        $serial->sendMessage("d");

} else if ($_GET['action'] == "off") {

    $serial->sendMessage("f");
}

$serial->deviceClose();

}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>ARDUINO</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> ARDUINO AND PHP COMMUNICATION </h1>

<a href="?action=on">ON</a></br>
<a href="?action=off">OFF</a></br>
```

I know I can make simple form like:

```
<select name="temperatur" size="1">
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
</select>
```

But I dont know how to setup it to auto send value "25" when I select it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax with jQuery for example:

```
<select id="temperatur">
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
</select>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#temperatur').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).val(),
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

then get the value into a php file like:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```